# gnome-calender in 18.04, no notification for reminders

Tags: 18.04, gnome, notification, calendar

I tried adding `events` to `gnome-calender` and set `1 day before` reminder notifications for various events. These events are on separate days. During the last couple of weeks, I got no notifications for these reminders. I started using `gnome-calender` only recently. Is there any fix ? Or, I should try moving to some other app to get reminder notifications ? Thanks.

I use 18.04 fully updated.